# Drive Folder ID from file

Tags: google-apps-script

after the renewal of DriveApp API I'm struggling to update my script. 
It was able to find the Drive Folder ID starting from a file. 
Basically starting from a Spreadsheet, I found what was the ID of the folder that contained the file. 
Now if i try:

```
var thisFile =(the file I have)
var newFile = (the file I want to add to the same folder)
var parentFold = thisFile.getParents()[0];
var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFold);
targetFolder.addFile(newFile);
```

The system sends an error at line 4 "No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it." (even if I open all the permissions).
Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `getParents()` method returns a [FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator).  It doesn't return the folder ID.  You need to get the folder:

```
var folder = folders.next();
```

The code given assumes that there is only one parent folder to the file.

### Updated Answer:

```
function copyToParent() {
  var thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById('file ID');
  //var newFile = (the file I want to add to the same folder)

  var parentFold = thisFile.getParents();//Get all parents - normally just one parent
  var folder = parentFold.next();//Get the first parent folder
  //Logger.log('folder name: ' + folder.getName());//For testing - log folder name
  folder.addFile(newFile);
}
```

### Old Answer:

This answer has unneeded steps.

Then get the ID of the folder:

```
var theId = folder.getId();
```

Full code:

```
function copyToParent() {
  var thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById('file ID');
  //var newFile = (the file I want to add to the same folder)

  var parentFold = thisFile.getParents();
  var folder = parentFold.next();
  var theId = folder.getId();
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(theId);

  Logger.log('targetFolder name: ' + targetFolder.getName());
  targetFolder.addFile(newFile);
};
```

Comment: circuitous. var targetFolder = thisFile.getParents().next();

Comment: Awesome!  Much better.

Comment: Re @ScampMichael's comment, wouldn't it be even simpler to say targetFolder = folder;?

Comment: See updated answer.  The original answer had unnecessary lines.